# Rails - Devise error: "Email can't be blank, password can't be blank" when create new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting an error which has been answered before, but none of the answers are working for me and I'm completely stumped.

I'm using devise but it is not registrable.

When I try to create a new user I get an error "Email can't be blank, password can't be blank". They definitely aren't blank as can be seen in the log. The parameters hash is working correctly. The transaction just rolls back immediately. I don't get this issue when creating a new user in console.

It works fine when editing an existing user.

Have addressed the strong parameters issue devise throws up.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help!

My code below.

Log:

```
    Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-29 10:37:33 +0000
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"8U+XxLIrE7MjOphsuorOwarggyZsj
3qTNQeap273QTo=", "user"=>{"name"=>"John Smith", "role"=>"MG", "client"=>""
, "email"=>"john@johnsmith.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "passw
ord_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORD
ER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x422fc88 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_passw
ord: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_create
d_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, curr
ent_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, nam
e: nil, client: nil, role: nil>, @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :passwor
d=>["can't be blank"], :name=>[], :role=>[], :client=>[], :password_confirmation
=>[]}>
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 238ms (Views: 231.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0m
s)
```

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    projects_path
 end

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :client
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name, :role, :client]
 end
end
```

Form for new user:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> stopped this user from being created:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :role %><br />
  <%= select :user, :role, options_for_select(@role) %></div>

<div id="client_input"><%= f.label :client %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :client %></div>


  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>


  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_user, :only => [:index,:new,:edit]
  before_filter :client_restriction, only: [:index, :show, :new]


  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @users }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @role = ["MG", "Client"]
  end

  def show
  @user = User.all
    @projects = Project.all      
  end


  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = ["MG", "Client"]
    end

   def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = ["MG", "Client"]
    @user.client == :client
    @user.role == :role

    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password].collect{|p| params[:user].delete(p)}
    else
      @user.errors[:base] << "The password you entered is incorrect." unless @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password])
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true) # To counter weird Devise error which logs users out after password change
        format.html { redirect_to projects_path, notice: 'Your account details were updated successfully' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your account has been deleted. Sorry to see you go!" }      
    end
    end

  def create
    @role = ["MG", "Client"]
    @user = User.new
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "New user successfully created" }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :text => "Could not create user", :status => :unprocessable_entity } # placeholder
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { render :action => :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect)
    end 


  def add_user
  end

    private 

  def get_user
    @current_user = current_user
  end
  def client_restriction
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are not authorised to create users" if current_user.role != "MG"
  end  
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:role, :name, :client, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :authenticity_token, project: [:name, :client, :phase], section: [:title, :position, :project_id], deliverable: [:file, :preview, :title, :project_id, :section_id], link: [:hyperlink, :title, :project_id, :section_id], embed: [:section_id, :embed_link, :title, :project_id])
    end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :members
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :sections    
  has_many :deliverables
  has_many :embeds
  has_many :links   

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects

end
```

Comment: `@user = User.new` is missing the hash from `user_params` method. what you need to do is:  `@user = User.new user_params`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create a blank `User`. Try:

```
def create
  # ...
  @user = User.new user_params
  # ...
end
```

Comment: How did I miss that?! Thanks very much. Although I went User.new(user_params)

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope its work for you

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :client
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,:password_confirmation, :name, :role, :client) }
end
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Just thought I'd reply for posterity as the other answer solved my issue. 
I tried this solution previously, but Devise should handle the :email, :password and :password_confirmation params itself. The only ones you have to add in are custom ones. Thanks.